# Need help creating editable checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

im trying to create an edit page that contains some checkboxes where its values are looped from a database. ive tried different combinations of code however i seem to be having problems in making it work properly, especially the checkboxes(the checkboxes is the only one im having problems with).

what happens with my code is that...

for example if all the checkboxes are checked and i unchecked the 2nd one and the 3rd one

```
 ✓ Dj Lorem        ■ Dj Ipsum
 ■ Dj Dolor        ✓ Dj Sit
 ✓ Dj Amet
```

after submitting it will look like this

```
 ✓ Dj Lorem        ✓ Dj Ipsum
 ✓ Dj Dolor        ■ Dj Sit
 ■ Dj Amet
```

the checked content goes up/the last checkbox is always the one that gets unchecked and so on(if you uncheck 2 checkboxes, the last 2 checkboxes are the ones that gets unchecked)

**edit_news.php(view)**

```
Edit News
<?php
    $id = $news_id;
    $attributes = array('class' => 'form form-horizontal','id'=>'form_news','name'=>'form_news');
    echo form_open(base_url() . 'cms/update_news/'.$id, $attributes);
?> 

News Title: <input type="text" class="w300" name="news_title" id="news_title" value="<?php echo $news1->news_title; ?>">
<?php
        $i=0;
        foreach($dj->result() as $d)
        {
            $q = $cdj->row($i);
        ?>
          <div class="span3">
              <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="cats[]" value="<?php echo $d->UID; ?>"<?php if($q->checked=="yes"){echo "checked";}else if($q->checked==""){};?> /> DJ <?php echo $d->dj_name;?>
                <input type="hidden" name="dj_id[]" value="<?php echo $d->UID; ?>">
              </label>

                </div>
                <?php
                $i=$i+1;
            }
        ?>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Save">
 </form>
```

the view php looks something like this

```
 Edit News

 News Title: ___Party at 6____ 
 Choose a DJ
 ■ Dj Lorem        ■ Dj Ipsum
 ■ Dj Dolor        ■ Dj Sit
 ■ Dj Amet
```

**cms.php (controller)**

```
public function news_edit($id)
{
    $data['dj'] = $this->cms_model->get_dj();
    $data['news1'] = $this->cms_model->get_one_news($id);
    $data['djnews'] = $this->cms_model->get_djnews($id);
    $data['cdj'] = $this->cms_model->get_cdj($id);
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $this->load->vars($data);
    $this->load->view('admin/news_edit');
}

public function update_news($id)
{
    $this->cms_model->update_news($id);
    redirect(base_url() . "cms/news_edit/".$id);
}
```

**cms_model.php(model)**

```
function get_dj(){
    return $this->db->select()->from("roster")->get();
}

function get_one_news($id){
    return $this->db->select()->from("news")->where("UID",$id)->get()->row();
}

function get_cdj($id){
        return $this->db->select()->from("news_dj")->where("news_id",$id)->get();   
}

function update_news($id)
{       
    $news_title = $this->input->post("news_title");

    $cats = $this->input->post("cats");
    $dj_id = $this->input->post("dj_id");

    $newdata = array('news_title'=>$news_title
                    );

    $this->db->where('UID', $id);
    $this->db->update('news', $newdata);

    $i=0;
    foreach($dj_id as $d)
    {
        if ($cats[$i] == ""){$check="no";}
        else{$check="yes";}
        $dj = array('dj_id'=>$d,'news_id'=>$id,'checked'=>$check);
        $this->db->where('dj_id', $d);
        $this->db->where('news_id', $id);
        $this->db->update('news_dj', $dj); 
        $i=$i+1;
    }
}
```

**news(sql)**

```
 UID       news_title
  6        Party at 6
  7        Event Cancelled on Monday
  8        and so on
```

**roster(sql)**

```
 UID       news_title
  1        Lorem
  2        Ipsum
  3        Dolor
  4        Sit
  5        Amet
```

**news_dj(sql)**

```
 dj_id     news_id    checked
  1        6          yes
  2        6          yes
  3        6          yes
  4        6          no
  5        6          no
```

ive ran out of ideas and i cant seem to fix it

thanks

Comment: +1 for very good explanation using example etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it set up oddly. `cats[]` will *only* contain elements that are checked, so checking if `$cats[$i] != ""` means that it will count how many are checked and with your loop, will assign the first `x` amount of DJs that are listed. When setting up the HTML, I'd suggest

```
name="cats[<?php echo $d->UID; ?>]" value=...
```

That way, it is indexed the way that you are expecting it in your update loop.  This would be the simplest way to solve your issue - otherwise, you could check the values that are checked against the DJ id's in the update.  But again, I chose to explain how to make it work the quickest for what you have ^^

**EDIT**

If you don't want to change your HTML, you can change your check from:

```
if ($cats[$i] == ""){$check="no";}
        else{$check="yes";}
```

To:

```
$check = (in_array($d, $cats)) ? "yes" : "no";
```

as that will see if the current DJ is in the list of submitted checkbox values.

Comment: thanks for the answer finally got it working. you're a lifesaver =D

Comment: The way you're matching IDs, using `$q = $cdj->row($i);` is really not recommended. There's no guarantee that row `$i` will be the same ID that is in your loop. Your model should sanitize the data in the proper format. It will make your loops easier and match correctly.

Comment: @Cryode Thanks for repeating me.... If it weren't check-boxes it would have the same ID if using the first method I put - but not with how the question's code is.  And the second method does check correctly for each DJ id.

Comment: I didn't repeat you, I elaborated on your answer to explain something else that was done poorly. You didn't mention the incorrect use of `row()`, and since your recommendations led to the OP solving his problem, I just added a comment.

Comment: @Cryode Ok, I understand now, I thought I had covered it in the first part, but the OP won't see your comment here since I doubt that he checks back and you didn't `@` him, so I thought it was better to get his attention on his question where he'd get the notification. ^^

Comment: OPs are included in comments I think